# How do we store the logs produced by morgan logger in a variable in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, logging, morgan

How do we store the logs produced by morgan logger in NodeJS?
Morgan and morgan-body generate response body in form of logs. How do I store those logs in my database or in a variable so that I can analyze the stored logs?

Answer (score 1):

you can write the logs into file.But for better you can use winston

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var morgan = require('morgan')
var path = require('path')

var app = express()

// log only 4xx and 5xx responses to console
app.use(morgan('dev', {
  skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }
}))

// log all requests to access.log
app.use(morgan('common', {
  stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), { flags: 'a' })
}))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan

You can read the log File and analyze later